# Criar um string resource ou uma classe de contantes?

Tags: java, android

Tenho uma aplicação no qual uso persistência de dados com `SharedPreference`. Desde o começo quando comecei criar aplicações, sempre criei uma classe, por exemplo, com nome `Consts` para armazenar variáveis do tipo `static final`, no qual não precisam ser alteradas e podem ser acessadas de qualquer parte do projeto. Veja um exemplo:

```
public static final String AUTHOR = "author";
```

Quando uso o `SharedPreference`, geralmente faço desta forma:

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
editor.putString(Consts.AUTHOR, "Jon Snow");
editor.commit();
```

Recentemente assistindo uma determinada vídeo aula de um desenvolvedor do Google, que trabalha como Android Developer, ele usou o *string resource* desta forma:

```
<string name="str_author" translatable="false">author</string>
```

Então no `SharedPreference` ele fez assim:

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
editor.putString(getString(R.string.str_author), "Jon Snow");
editor.commit();
```

Esses dois códigos possuem a mesma finalidade. Mas ai que vem a questão que me levou a pensar um pouco.

- Devo criar um *string resource* ou uma classe de contantes?
- Ou essa opção de usar o *string resource* seria somente para `SharedPreference`?
- Em questão de performance e/ou praticidade, qual seria melhor opção?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para o caso que refere, chave para um valor guardado na SharedPreferences, deve usar constantes.

O resource string destina-se a texto para ser apresentado ao usuário, aproveitando as suas capacidades de formatação, estilo, pluralização e idioma.

O uso em SharedPreference não aproveita nenhuma dessas características, por isso não encontro justificação<sup>(1)</sup> para ser usado aí.

O uso de um tipo primitivo ou String, declarado como `static final`, tem um custo muito menor do que usar um método para obter a string dos resources.

<sub>(1) - A não ser que tenha guardados valores diferentes por idioma e os queira aceder por uma única chave.</sub>

Referências:

- [Recursos de string.](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html)

Comment: Sempre usei contantes para SharedPreferences, mas fiquei encucado porque o cara do Google usou string resource para a situação. Ele usou translatable="false" para que não seja traduzido.

Comment: É como disse na resposta, não vejo vantagem nenhuma em usar string resources como chave para um valor guardado na SharedPreferences, a não ser que o valor seja diferente por idioma. Em termos de preformance, o string resources é "transformado" no valor usando `getString()` durante a execução. A constante é "transformada" no valor durante a compilação.

Comment: Porém não tem como usar uma variável criada numa classe de constante dentro do XML, a não ser que instancie primeiro.

Comment: Não entendi...!

Comment: Era só um comentário! =D Obrigado pela resposta.

Answer (score 0):

Pesquisei sobre o assunto e o resultado ainda foi um pouco misto, porém, basear-me-ei na documentação oficial.

**"*Devo criar um string resource ou uma classe de contantes?*"**

A [documentação oficial](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html) sugere (por exemplos) utilizar *string resource* para [SharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html), porém não acredito que seja uma "verdade escrita na pedra" e se você utilizar ou não o arquivo de resource para expor dados para o usuário.

**"*Em questão de performance e/ou praticidade, qual seria melhor opção?*"**

Quando a performance não acredito que seja algo que gere *delays* na aplicação, porém, a praticidade de utilizar *string resource* é muito grande, visto que está disponível a partir de toda a aplicação. Já no caso de classes constantes você precisa importar a classe (o que também não seria grande problema, já que a classe `R` também seria importada).
Lendo a documentação, acredito ser melhor o uso dos resources, visto que ela cria um ID único de acesso global.

**Algumas ressalvas:**

A pasta de `resources` é um passível de [internacionalização](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html) (não encontrei a página em PT-BR), se você criar um arquivo que contenha para uso na SharedPrefference, trate-o para ser "global" ou seja, mantenha-o na pasta raiz, ou trate-o por idioma.

Ack Lay: No momento não consigo fazer um teste para ver o resultado usando pastas de outros idiomas sem usar o raiz, farei o teste e posteriormente editarei a questão com o resultado.

Espero que tenha ajudado.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta Carlos! Quanto ao "A pasta de resources é um passível de internacionalização[...]" para este caso não faz muito diferença, por isso é usado o `translatable="false"` para que não seja traduzido.